# EU Blue Card Germany without degree

Tags: germany, eu, blue-card

About me:

I finished my computer engineer career in 2016 but don't have the degree because i still haven't delivered my thesis ( i'm unable to do so at the moment). I also have 3 years of experience in the field and am a Venezuelan citizen

Question:

According to the following [post](http://www.eu-bluecard.com/eu-blue-card-germany/) under the "If You Have Found a Job in Germany" title, you require a university degree for unregulated professions to apply but, if i keep reading it says( as i understand it)  under the " How to Apply for Germany EU Blue Card" title that it is only needed for unrecognized professions. So my question beeing, do i need the degree based on my career ( comp engineering - full stack dev) or not.